# is an HTTP/1.1 request implicitly keep-alive by default?

Tags: http

***Solved***: pasting the bytes here made me realise that I was missing empty lines between chunks...

---

Does an HTTP/1.1 request need to specify a `Connection: keep-alive` header, or is it always keep-alive by default?

[This guide](http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html#SECTION00052000000000000000) made me think it would; that, when my http server gets a 1.1 request, it is keep-alive unless explicitly receiving a `Connection: close` header.

I ask since my the different client behaviour of `ab` and `httperf` is driving me mad enough to wonder my sanity on this one...

---

Here's what `httperf --hog --port 42042 --print-reply body` sends:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: httperf/0.9.0
Host: localhost
```

And here's my server's response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Length: 18

12
Hello World      1
0
```

`httpref` promptly prints out the response, but then just sits there, neither side closing the connection and `httpref` not exiting.

Where's my bug?

Comment: Yes, keep-alive is the HTTP/1.1 default.

Comment: content length in chunked encoding doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [RFC 2616, section 8.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1.2):

> A significant difference between HTTP/1.1 and earlier versions of HTTP is that persistent connections are the default behavior of any HTTP connection. That is, unless otherwise indicated, the client SHOULD assume that the server will maintain a persistent connection, even after error responses from the server.