# How to enable Keep Alive connection in AWS S3 or CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, keep-alive

How to enable Keep Alive connection in AWS S3 or CloudFront? I uploaded images to S3 and found that the urls don't have keep alive connection. They cannot be cached by client application even I added cache-control headers to each image file.

Answer (score 2):

From the tag wiki for Keep-Alive:

> A feature of HTTP where the same connection is used for multiple
>   requests, speeding up downloading of web pages with multiple
>   resources.

I'm not aware of any relation that this has to cache behavior. I usually see mentions of Keep-Alive headers in relation to long-polling, which wouldn't make any sense to enable on S3.

I think you are incorrectly linking keep-alive headers with your browser's ability to cache static content. The cache-control headers should be all that is needed for caching of static content in the browser.

Are you verifying that the response from CloudFront includes the cache-control headers you have set on the S3 objects? Perhaps you need to invalidate the CloudFront cache after you updated the headers.

Comment: Keep-alive connections are the norm -- they allow the browser to send the next request without the overhead of a new TCP connection.  CloudFront sets an explicit `Connection: keep-alive` header; S3 adds no `Connection:` header at all, which [in HTTP/1.1 is supposed to be considered equivalent behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927599/1695906) -- keep-alive is enabled if `Connection: close` is not sent.  OP may be observing the fact that S3 doesn't return the header and assuming that's significant, when in fact it isn't. The root cause of a browser caching issue will be elsewhere.

Comment: Here is one of image urls: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mysampletest/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536.png I used a REST client to access this url. There is no Connection: keep-alive header. However, this is a url from BBC website that also stored in S3. http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/bbcle/images/width/live/p0/3h/c2/p03hc212.jpg/624 . You can see that it got Connection: keep-alive header.

Comment: If the url no Connection: keep-alive header, the image cannot be cached. I am writing an iOS app that will access the images on my S3 bucket. All images files could not be cached. I have spent a lot of time to find the issues. Finally, I realised that the issue is about Connection: keep-alive header. I wonder to know to how configure the S3 or CloudFront to fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Related to your question I think the problem is in setting correct TTL(>0) to your origin/behaviours in Cloudfront.

Also AWS Cloudfront (from 30 March 2017) [enables you to set up custom read and keep-alive timeouts](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/announcing-configure-read-timeout-and-keep-alive-timeout-values-for-your-amazon-cloudfront-custom-origins/) for custom origins.